# Does "be sitting" mean "action" or "state"?

Tags: present-continuous

Given a sentence:

A couple is sitting on the bench.

Does that describe a man and a woman who is in the middle of the action? Or does it refer to a couple who is seated?

Comment: It can mean either, usually it means seated.  The act of sitting is usually so transient that by the time you say, "look they're sitting." they've already sat.  But with a few extra words you can get across the meaning of "in the middle of" For example, "They are *just* sitting *down* to dinner now.  "He was *in the middle of sitting down* when the phone rang.

Comment: @Jim, why don't you post that as an answer? I'm tempted to steal it and post it as an answer myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:

> A couple is sitting on the beach

is technically ambiguous. It could mean either:

> Joe got into that chair hours ago, and he **is still sitting** in it.

or

> Hold on a minute--Joe **is sitting down** now, and I want to see if this whoopee cushion works.

In common usage, however, "is sitting" is more likely to be understood as describing someone who has already seated himself or herself and is currently inhabiting the chair, beach towel, or whatever. If you wanted to indicate the contrary, you would rephrase the sentence to something like:

> An elderly couple was just sitting down on the beach.

to indicate that they were still in the process of entering a seated position.